# Python: Set list elements as dict values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.7

Short question and probably short answer, but I do not get it^^

```
d = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 0, 'd' : 0}
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to set the list values to the dictionary such that

```
d = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
```

Of course

```
d['a'], d['b'], d['c'], d['d'] = l
```

will make it, but that cant be the right way to do it. What if I have 50 values ... A loop that zips `d` and `l` will work as well.

But there is something short like `d.values = l`, isn't it?

Thanks for helping!  :)

Edit: I’m using Python 3.7, so the dict is ordered by insertion.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, `d` is not a dictionary but a syntax error, `l` is a *list*. Dictionaries and sets are not ordered, so you can't just connect values in a set to keys in a dictionary.

Comment: You need to have an additional structure that will indicate the intended order of the keys. or use OrderedDict.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Yes, i made a typo, sorry. Edited it.
In Python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered by insertion.

Comment: For context, Perl allows something similar using hash slices. If `%d = (a=>0, b=>0, c=>0, d=>)`, then `@d{qw/a b c d/} = (1,2,3,4)` does the desired pairwise assignment `$d{a}=1`, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no short-cut. You need to use `dict.update` with a list of pairs.

```
d.update(zip(d, l))
```

Comment: Your answer is neat, I didn't think about using zip. Also you can take the first part out of your answer as OP edited his dict syntax. I also don't know why someone downvoted you I upvoted to even it out

Comment: @chepner: Great, this is a nice one! :)

Comment: @Jab: He edited to a complete new answer. Probably that’s why there was a downvote ... It was not mine :)

Comment: Eh, I think the downvote was originally warranted. I missed that you had already mentioned using `zip(d,l)`. This is basically the same answer, but with the emphasis on using `zip` as the simplest available option. (And I also forgot that `update` would work with a list of pairs, rather than requiring you create a `dict` first.)

Comment: Basically it might be the same answer, but it is much nicer than using a for loop. `update` is the pythonic way I was looking for :)

Comment: Also, this is why `PEP8` says no using `l` as a variable name that's why I got mismatched. I thought it was a `1` haha

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.7+ dicts are ordered in the order the items are inserted. Therefore the following would be correct.

```
d = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 0, 'd' : 0}
for i, k in enumerate(d.keys(), 1):
    d[k] = i
```

Or you could use something like the following:

```
d['a'], d['b'], d['c'], d['d'] = range(1,5) #or 1, 2, 3, 4
```

**Edit**

One liner for you using a dict comprehension:

```
d = {key: val for val, key in enumerate(d.keys(), 1)}
```

Comment: Yes, a for loop will make it. But i would use `for key, val in zip(d, l)` instead. But there is no one-line solution without a loop?

Comment: I added one into my answer

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Only in Python 3.7 is the order guaranteed; in 3.6 it's an implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: No, this is not what I’m looking for. First, `l` is just an example. I get it as a return value so it can also be `[-5, 23, 1, 0]`. And then I want to update my dict with that returning list. So yes, `d = {key : val for key, val in zip(d, l)}` will work. But because there is something like `d['a'], d['b'], ... = l`, I thought there must be something better without a loop. Something like `d.values = l`.

Comment: Well, my reading of the question must have been wrong. As yes you can do what I did with zip as you say or you can use @chepner's method as well, they both will do the same. See [here](https://repl.it/repls/AnnualWelllitFlashdrives) they both have the same result. I thought it was just trying to get a-d to equal 1-4